# SQL Stored Procedure to get Date and Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to create a stored procedure which can retrieve the datetime less than or greater than current sys date.. in my table,startdate and enddate has the value as 'datetime'

How do I get details between startdate and enddate in SQL stored procedure?

thanks in advance

Comment: There are infinitely many dates and times that are less than or greater than sysdate. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: hi iam using two dates.. startdate and enddate defined as smalldatetime

Comment: The database seems like SQL Server. What do you mean by "date and time are as separate fields"? Can you post the structure of your table?

Comment: hi kamal i have updated the question

Answer (score 3):

Considering this table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dates](
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

I assume that if you pass a date you want to know which rows satisfy the condition: startDate < date < EndDate. If this is the case you can use the query:

```
select * 
from Dates 
where convert(datetime, '20/12/2010', 103) between StartDate and EndDate;
```

A stored procedure could look like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDataWithinRange]
    @p_Date datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    from Dates 
    where @p_Date between StartDate and EndDate;
END
```

Answer (score 3):

eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE DATEDIFF ('d',mydatefield ,getdate() ) < 3
```

gets within 3 days

Comment: you ment  where datediff('d',mydatefield , getdate()) between -3 and 3

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to filter data in a table based on a date range. If this is the case (I'm having some trouble understanding your question), you'd do something like this:

```
select    *
from      MyTable m
where     m.Date between @DateFrom and @DateTo
```

Now, I'm assuming your filtering dates are put into the variables `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo`.

Comment: did you test the answer , before posting the answer?

Comment: nope. didn't want to fire up SQL server on my netbook. i'd like to think i do this type of query enough that i don't have to test this for the purposes of giving an answer that is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are two things:

1> To get todays date we can write
SET @today_date = GETTDDT();  

2> To get Current time we can us ethe following query:

SET @today_time = (SELECT                                            
                digits(cast(hour(current time) as decimal(2,0)))||   
                digits(cast(minute(current time) as decimal(2,0)))|| 
                digits(cast(second(current time) as decimal(2,0)))   
              FROM sysibm/sysdummy1);
```